# permanently remove an item from a list of a class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, list, class, object

i have a class:

```
Public Class labelsTag
    Public Property tag_name As String = ""
    Public Property values As New DataTable
End Class
```

i have an object that contains a list of labelsTag, but i need to remove the `tag_name` from the third item of the list.

Comment: What means "remove"? You cannot remove the property, you could set it to `Nothing` for example. You know how to access a list by index? Then you already know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what you mean.  Assume `myList` is a `List(of LabelsTag)` you cant remove the *property*, but you can remove/clear the *value*:

```
myList(2).tag_name = ""
```

To remove an item from a specific index in the list (as in Title):

```
myList.RemoveAt(ndx)
```

where `ndx` is the index of the item to remove `0`, `1`, `3` etc

Comment: is there any way to remove the property `tag_name` from `mylist(0)` but leave it `mylist(1)`?

Comment: you cannot remove a *Property*  do you mean clear the *value*? ie set it to ` "" ` (`String.Empty`)?